# Is it necessary to wrap plugs between icicle lights to protect rain or water from seeping in?

Tags: electrical, lighting

I've wrapped plugs between icicle lights to protect rain or water from seeping in. Is this necessary for Christmas decorations?

[image]

Comment: Are these actually exterior lights? [They don't look to be.] If so, the plugs/sockets should already be watertight, otherwise things go bang. If not, don't put them outdoors.

Comment: This is entirely a matter of opinion and risk tolerance.

Answer (score 5):

No*.

In 25 years of holiday lighting in a rainy and snowy climate I've never once had a breaker blow due to moisture. I *may* have blown a tiny fuse once or twice, but that also may have been due to excessive chaining.

Clean water doesn't conduct particularly well, and it doesn't tend to conduct enough to trip breakers in this scenario. It almost needs to be laid in a puddle for that to happen.

Caveat: If any of it's in an area where folks are likely to be grabbing onto it in the rain or whatever, use good judgement. Stranger things have happened than an electrified surface.

* In my opinion. That's all you'll get with this question... opinion.

Comment: Agree, we have year-round chained lighting outside with similar unsealed plugs and no issues in a snowy rainy climate, and GFCI never tripped.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the climate, and how diligently you want to prevent water intrusion vs how much you can afford to spend on it.

The best waterproofing I've seen for this type of plug is silicone gaskets that can seal tightly against the prongs. I don't use these because they're relatively expensive, but if I tripped GFCIs more often, I'd probably use these.

Some people will tape the connection, and that can work with the right tape and low-moisture climates.

Yet others will put every connection into a small tupperware container, and use caulk to seal the cable holes. This seems like overkill to me and it looks terrible except in the yard where it's barely visible. There are some custom shaped plastic containers that snap closed and have rubber seals at both ends, that come in various colors (green/white/black/orange) made for extension cords, they're a little bulky for a connection like in your picture, and they tend to be a little expensive. I see them in use around my neighborhood and they seem like they'd work well but I don't have firsthand knowledge of how effective they are.

I have not used plastic wrap like this, because it seems like it would get wet in my climate and trap moisture against the plugs.

Since I've only tripped GFCI 1 or 2 times, I only protect my connections where they're 1) in the yard and 2) those crappy lamp-wire extension cords. All the rest get tucked under an eave or pointed down or something to keep snow from falling directly on them, and forget about it.

Comment: "trap moisture against the plugs." I think that's the kicker right there... Probably _more_ likely to get water building up inside the wrapping and working its way into the socket with this somewhat haphazard wrapping than without.

Comment: I've never had a problem with outdoor lights, but if I was really concerned, I think the best solution would be to just put dielectric grease into each plug.

Comment: i encircle the flat base of the plug around the mating male prongs with hotglue, then warm up each side of the plug with a hair dryer, then plug them together and hold fast until it cools, which forms a durable yet reversible seal/lock between the two connections.

Comment: On more temporary connections, use a small old pill bottle or film canister and put the plugs up into it and keep it vertical. This stops water running into it, while also allowing plenty of ventilation to dry out any condensation or splatter-based moisture that could still enter up through the open bottom.